# What is the best way to attach JS, CSS and all other vendor files?

Tags: php

Lets suppose you've a PHP site, and there is alot of `Javascript` and `CSS` files.
But every `JS` & `CSS` file will not be attach on all pages.
**Some like :** You've *18* `CSS` files and *23* `JS` files and the sum of these files is *31*. And you've 3 `PHP` files i.e :

1. index.php
2. about.php
3. contact.php

Not all these *31* files will attach with on every single `PHP` page.
*5* `CSS` and *10* `JS` files will attach with `index.php`
As it is *10* `CSS` and *12* `JS` files will attach with a `about.php` and so on...
Now the question is that, "What will you do with these *31* files, either you put all these file on one page then include on all the `PHP` files or attach with respactive page?"

Answer (score 1):

Combine all your CSS files into one file. If you use a tool for that, you can keep separate source files (easy to work with) and compile them and minimize them into a single file for download.

Do the same with JavaScript.

That way, you've got only two files that are also quite small. These files can be statically served, and with the proper headers, the client will cache them very well. There is some overhead of sending more data than you need for each page, but you've got much fewer request because everthing is in a couple of files and those files can be cached between page requests.

Examples of online tools to try out the idea:

- [cssminifier.com/](http://cssminifier.com/) for CSS
- [jscompress.com/](http://jscompress.com/) online JavaScript minification
- [Leafo's PHP SCSS compiler](http://leafo.net/scssphp/) (I use this one for my personal sites).

Comment: helpful ! let me search out.

Answer (score 1):

The choice is yours and really depends on how far you want to improve your performance. You really have 2 choices:

1. The easy choice is to just compile all the files into a single css and a single js file and include them in all your pages.
2. The harder choice but a bit more performant (depending on the size of all your javascript and css) is to have one css/js file with all the shared css/js and then another css/js file for each page with the specific css/js for that page.

Note that solution 2 is not only more difficult to pull off but it might even be slower in some cases. What slows down your performance the most is having multiple http requests. So if you decided to load those 31 files in your page without compiling them, that would be very detrimental to your performance.

Some good tools for compiling your css and js are:

http://gulpjs.com/
or
http://gruntjs.com/

which run on nodejs https://nodejs.org/

Comment: If I chose the second option so, it can creating issue of slow loading(downloading pages) ?

Comment: @MHK I mean it will only be 2 extra http requests. It's not likely to make any significant negative impact. My point was that unless your css/js are significantly reduced by using method 2 it really is not worth the hassle. Now if you have a huge website option 2 might be the way to go, but in most cases going with option 1 is better since it is easier to implement and maintain. The most important thing to do is to make sure you don't have something like 30 separate files.

Comment: Another thing to note is that you can go for more advanced methods of loading css such as loading your critical CSS inline (this is a blocking request) and then the non critical CSS asynchronously. Searching for "CSS above the fold" you can find some good resources about this. That option can be used together with the options I suggest (more or less). It is though a much harder to pull off option, in terms of organizing your css correctly.